# Visual Studio Message: "The TypeScript SDK has been deprecated."

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

For the last few months, Visual Studio shows a yellow message above the editor tabs when I open a TypeScript file:

"The TypeScript SDK has been deprecated. To enable TypeScript compilation, upgrade your project to use the 'Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild' NuGet package."

This is interesting for a few reasons:

1. TypeScript compilation works just fine currently, so adding the NuGet package won't "enable TypeScript compilation" any better than the built-in TypeScript compiler.
2. Visual Studio 17.3 Preview's release notes say, "The TypeScript 4.7 language service and compiler are included in Visual Studio."
3. I have installed the NuGet package, and the only difference I can see is the removal of the yellow deprecation message.

These are my questions:

1. What is the TypeScript compiler (which is built into Visual Studio) versus the TypeScript SDK (which is also built into Visual Studio but is deprecated)?
2. Why does Visual Studio want me to use this NuGet package?  What specific features will it give me (besides getting rid of the yellow message)?  Like I said, my current configuration already compiles my TypeScript files, and Microsoft continues to update the built-in TypeScript compiler.  What's the point of a NuGet package?

Answer (score 0):

[image: TypeScriptWarningBar]

I saw the yellow warning bar today after upgrading to VS 2022 17.8.0 and changing my projects to target .NET 8. It's curious because we've used a PackageReference to Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild for a while now. I did some research to try to answer my questions (and your questions), and the best I could come up with were some quotes from recent Microsoft Learn articles.

This [TypeScript support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) section mentions MSBuild scenarios:

> In MSBuild compilation scenarios such as ASP.NET Core, the TypeScript NuGet package is the recommended method of adding TypeScript compilation support to your project.

The article [Compile TypeScript code (ASP.NET Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/compile-typescript-code-nuget?view=vs-2022) expounds further:

> Use the TypeScript NuGet package to add TypeScript support to your ASP.NET Core projects. Starting in Visual Studio 2019, it is recommended that you use the NuGet package instead of the TypeScript SDK. The TypeScript NuGet package provides greater portability across different platforms and environments.
>
> For ASP.NET Core projects, one common usage for the NuGet package is to compile TypeScript using the .NET Core CLI. In .NET scenarios, the NuGet package is the preferred option, and it's the only way to enable TypeScript compilation using .NET Core CLI commands such as `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish`. Also, for MSBuild integration with ASP.NET Core and TypeScript, choose the NuGet package.

Finally, the [Project Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2022#project-types-1) section of the [Project migration and upgrade reference for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2022) article describes the old TypeScript project support:

> The TypeScript SDK has been deprecated in Visual Studio 2022 and is no longer installed by default in any workload. Projects that compile TypeScript should install the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild NuGet package. To support projects that can't be upgraded immediately, the TypeScript SDK is still available as an optional component in the Visual Studio installer, as well as in Visual Studio Marketplace

So, I don't know an answer for your question #1 or why I started seeing the yellow bar today. But the answer to your question #2 appears to be that VS recommends the NuGet package to enable build and publish scenarios outside of VS, e.g., cross-platform .NET CLI use with `dotnet`, MSBuild, and VS Code.